# Getting incorrect values when @property and @synthesize is used

Tags: ios

I've created two ViewControllers `ViewControllerA` and `ViewControllerB`. I've taken an `NSString` object `myString` in `ViewControllerA` and want to get the value of this in `ViewControllerB`. So, I've declared

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *myString
```

and

```
@synthesize myString
```

in ViewControllerA.m. But when I create an object of `ViewControllerA` in `ViewControllerB` and try to get the values of `myString` like

```
NSString *tempString = viewControllerBobject.myString
```

then I'm get a `null` value. How to get the correct value?

Comment: In your question you say that `myString` is a property of `ViewControllerA`. Yet you send a message to `ViewControllerB`: `viewControllerBobject.myString`.

Comment: are you using ARC, else you need to retain that string value.

Comment: @HinataHyuga I'm not using ARC

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting `(null)` because the string isn't set yet.

**Try:**

```
viewControllerBobject.myString = @"Hello World!";
NSString *tempString = viewControllerBobject.myString;
NSlog(@"tempString= %@", tempString);
```

What result do you get?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided much detail, but I suspect your problem is that you're creating a new instance of view controller A, instead of getting a reference to the one you already have where you set the value of the string. How you get that reference depends on how your app is set up, and how the two view controllers relate to each other. You'll need to provide more detail, if you need help with that.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the correct value.

The value of string property in VCA is nil. When you create VC1 a string property called string is synthesised. But it is pointing to nowhere (its value has not been set) thus it is nil. 
Therefore,when you create an VCA instance in VCB, the property of VCA is still nil.
You need to set the value of that property to some string. Then all VCA instance will have that default value.
OR you need to set the value of that property on a concrete instance of VCA, then ,that concrete instance will have that value.

Answer (score 0):

After this line `NSString *tempString = viewControllerBobject.myString`, add this `[tempString retain];`